# What heuristic functions can I use for a graph based (non-grid) A*?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, a-star, heuristics

I'm learning the A* path finding algorithm and all of the examples I'm finding are grid based. Because of this, all their heuristics functions rely on some sort of physical distance (ie Manhattan based, Diagonal or Euclidian).

But what if instead of a grid we have a freeform graph? Say the example below where `S` is the start and `G` is the goal:

```
S---A
|   
|   G
|   |
B---C---D
```

In this case a 'as the crow flies' approximation wouldn't be meaningful because this graph is equivocal to

```
S---A
|   
B---C---D
    |
    G
```

So what kind of heuristic function could I use in this case?

Comment: A good way to find heuristic function is to consider "relaxed problem" where you relax constraints of the actual problems, allowing "illegal moves" to be legals. http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse573/12au/slides
/03-heuristics.pdf
In your case, have you considered relaxing all cost to 1, and use a standard BFS to find distance between 2 nodes? Such distance could be a heuristic for distance between 2 nodes.

Comment: @Tuan333 Wouldn't using BFS defeat the purpose of resorting to A*?

Comment: Heuristics are often estimates that are based on the 'environment' in which the search is performed. What is the context in which you have this freeform graph?

Comment: @slider But this is BFS on a un-weighted tree. A* will compute the actual cost on the weighted tree. However, I see your point. Heuristic function is best done fast sometimes, BFS isn't that fast. Nevertheless, it will definitely yield a heuristic (run BFS once, then use its results as you run your A*)

Comment: @slider No context in particular. Lets say its a relationship graph and I want to know the degrees of separation between S and G. How would I estimate the approximate distance from any node to any other node?

Comment: @Tuan333 I'm already assuming all costs are 1 (hence the lack of weights). The question is, how do I estimate the distance for the rest? I don't know how many nodes are left.

Comment: Heuristics are an attempt to use additional information that you have to solve the problem more quickly. If there is no information about the problem other than the graph itself, there isn't a useful way to incorporate heuristic search.

Comment: I don't understand why manhattan distance does not work here ? It is still not an overestimate..

Comment: @HirakSarkar Because what is the distance manhattan distance from `S` to `G`? Keep in mind, this is a graph and not a grid. I wrote 2 equivalent forms of the same graph, but if you were to treat them like a grid and get the manhattan distance from `S` to `G`, the result would be different.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I got your point. But if we think that each edge of the graph is of unit length. Then the distance between S and G is still 3. I think I am missing something and may sound really stupid :P

Comment: @HirakSarkar How can we find the distance between D and G without actually calculating it? The point of the heuristic is that we are estimating it without actually going through the work of calculating it.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Okay I got your point. So you are basically asking there is a graph G and with positive weights now you want to search for G node from S node with A*, and you want a heuristic. Am I correct? You specifically meant there are *no* grid structure so it is a simple graph !!

Comment: @HirakSarkar Correct.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg In that case if there is no additional information and the graph is really really large then we can take minimum edge length as the heuristic. It is admissible because S is not goal node. Now if we take anything greater then we can always construct the graph with G present in the second level of BFS. Am I making sense ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64206/discussion-between-david-grinberg-and-hirak-sarkar).

Answer (score 4):

There is no heuristic that will improve the running time of Dijkstra's algorithm in the general case.

Heuristics are useful when a specific problem has additional *structure*. Graphs that are embedded in the plane have exactly this: A notion of straight-line distance which can be used as a heuristic, as in your example.

Consider the analogy of sorting. In the general case we know that sorting is O(nlogn) for an O(n)-length array. However, if our data satisfies the condition that the numbers in the array are in the range 0 to k where k << n, then we can sort them in O(n) with a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

In your example you do not give any additional structure of the input data that could possible be used to improve the run time of Dijkstra's algorithm for the general case, so you will not find any useful heuristics.